# PHP Crear Api Rest con controladores en Slim3

Tags: php, mysql, rest, slim3

Estoy aprendiendo el framework Slim3 para crear apis rest/full, me encontrado varios ejemplos, por ejemplo en routes.php

```
$app->group('/v1', function () {
    $this->group('/auth', function () {
        $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/login', 'App\controllers\AuthController:login');
        $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/logout', 'App\controllers\AuthController:logout');
        $this->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/signup', 'App\controllers\AuthController:signup');
    });

    $this->group('/events', function () {
        $this->get('', 'App\controllers\EventController:getEvents');
        $this->post('', 'App\controllers\EventController:createEvent');

        $this->group('/{eventId}', function () {
            $this->get('', 'App\controllers\EventController:getEvent');
            $this->put('', 'App\controllers\EventController:updateEvent');
            $this->delete('', 'App\controllers\EventController:deleteEvent');            
        });
    });
});
```

Pero los controllers no ser como crearlos, estoy un poco perdido con este framework.
De paso he buscado y encontrado lo siguiente [Slim 3 Very simple REST Skeleton](https://github.com/pabloroca/slim3-simple-rest-skeleton)

Lo he descargado descomprimido y creado las tablas necesarias, pero no acaba de funcionar, diría que se tiene que instalar de alguna forma que desconozco.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar como usar composer: https://styde.net/que-es-composer-y-como-usarlo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomándote del Controller de ejemplo [app/src/Controllers/_Controller.php](https://github.com/pabloroca/slim3-simple-rest-skeleton/blob/master/app/src/Controllers/_Controller.php)

La propiedad `autoload` del [composer.json](https://github.com/pabloroca/slim3-simple-rest-skeleton/blob/master/composer.json) dice que el namespace `App` se resuelve al subdirectorio `app/src`. Por lo tanto el namespace `App\Controllers` se resuelve al directorio `app/src/Controllers`.

Tus controllers debieran ser ubicados en la carpeta `app/src/Controllers` y tener la forma

AuthController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers; // <-- sin esto, el autoloader no los encontrará

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use App\DataAccess\_DataAccess;

/**
 * Class AuthController.
 */
class AuthController extends _Controller
{
 ... acá tus métodos ...
}
```

EventController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use App\DataAccess\_DataAccess;

/**
 * Class EventController.
 */
class EventController extends _Controller
{
     ... acá tus métodos ...
}
```

Y llamarlos en las rutas como:

```
App\Controllers\AuthController
```

y

```
App\Controllers\EventController
```

Puesto que el `namespace` donde están definidos es `App\Controllers` con `Controllers` con C mayúscula.

Dentro de tus controllers tienes que crear los métodos para ejecutar las acciones definidas por tus rutas (`login`, `getEvent`, etc), puesto que el controller genérico del skeleton no tiene esos métodos.